# Play2 - Subdomains

Tags: java, routes, playframework, playframework-2.0, subdomain

I want to create a network like stackexchange just with subdomains.

for example

```
subdomain1.test.com
subdomain2.test.com
subdomain3.test.com
subdomain4.test.com
```

I also want to have all websites in one app so I can scale and service them easier.

How do I do this in play2?

Can i specify a subdomain in `routes`?

pseudo code

```
GET     subdomain1/                           controllers.Application.index()
GET     subdomain2/                           controllers.Application.index()
```

Comment: No I searched for it but I could not find any information about this topic.

Comment: I don't even know how to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not work: if `router` contains two routes with the same type and target action it will use only first. For fastest solution you can just create a wrapping method(s), which will do what you need and use them on the view/controller level:

`route`

```
GET   /home    controllers.Application.index
```

`Application controller`

```
public static String linkMeta(play.api.mvc.Call path) {
    return "http://meta.domain.tld" + path;
}
```

Template samples:

```
<a href='@Application.linkMeta(routes.Application.index)'>Absoulte URL link to meta's index</a>
URL: http://meta.domain.tld/home

<a href='@routes.Application.index'>Relative URL to meta's index</a>
URL: /home
```

Comment: I have a follow up question. Let's say the user visits the url `subdomain2.test.com`. How does play know which function it should call? (I want to have one app to handle different websites)

Comment: it will call the same route: ie `GET / controllers.Application.index` - in the index() method you can check which domain is it and render other output for meta or main domain etc. BTW i really doubt if stack exchange is a single application.